# matplotlib: (re-)plot ping standard-input data. Doable?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I recently started tinkering with python and the matplotlib module(1.1.0) shipped with Enthought Python Distribution(the free version one).
I thought of an interesting project I could do and came up with something like this:

- get ping of an internet address
- pipe that via `sys.stdin` into python script

now in the python script:

- regex the answer time, if there is no answer time: use `NaN` or just 0 as number
- plot data via matplotlib
- add continuously data

I managed to get the ping via this: ping stackoverflow.com | python script.py
get the answertime wasn't particulary hard. But when it comes to plotting the data. I am stuck. I know there is an animation module inside matplotlib, but I think a timer-based plot would be harder to program than this, and I don't know how events are used anyway. What I want:

- Wait for sys.stdin to get a new string and thus the ping time
- Add it to the data array
- Plot the data array
  But it doesn't seem to be that easy. Besides this, Error handling is not yet done..
  Unfortunately I couldn't find any comparable code, although I did a lot of googling about it :/ Maybe this design is not meant to be like this..

Does anybody have an idea how to accomplish this replotting? It doesn't need to be efficient, as the ping only comes in every second or so..
I thought about buffering the incoming stdin and do a regular timer-based plot, but I have now idea to do that.

Thank you in advance,

Jonas

## Update1:

I can get rid of this error by using:

```
l1.set_xdata(range(len(data)))
```

before the `l1.set_ydata(..)`, but still it doesn't plot anything and the window doesn't respond either. At least it shows the plot axis.

## Code

```
import sys
import re
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    if sys.stdin.isatty():
        print "Please use a pipe as stdin\nExample: ping stackoverflow.com | python script.py"
        return 0
    regex = re.compile('time=(\d+.\d+)')
    data = []
    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_yscale('linear') # or log
    ax.grid(True)

    l1, = ax.plot(data)
    fig.show()

    while True:
        #get ping, if no string: stream has ended
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        if line == '':
            break
        #conversion: 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=45 time=100.873 ms --> 100.873
        match = regex.findall(line)
        number = 0.

        if len(match) > 1:
            raise ValueError()
        if len(match) == 1:
            try:
                number = float(match[0])
            except ValueError as e:
                print e
        #add number to array, plot the data
        data.append(number)
        l1.set_xdata(range(len(data)))
        l1.set_ydata(data)

        ax.relim()
        ax.autoscale()

        plt.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you first have `plt.show()`, do not use that. Instead use `fig.show()` there. And then just `plt.draw()` in your loop. The rest seems good. The thing is that `plt.show()` starts a mainloop, locking further execution (outside the events for the figure). `fig.show()` seems not to, however the buttons probably will not work like this (I didn't try).

You will have to add autoscale though:

```
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale()
plt.draw()
# And this allows you to at least close the window (and crash the program by that ;))
fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

But really it should be cleaner not use pyplot for this. For that look into how to [embed matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/user_interfaces/index.html) into a gui, it is really easy and can be done for a couple of different gui toolkits.

Comment: Thanks so far. I updated the code.
Unfortunately, it still gives me an Error:
RuntimeError: xdata and ydata must be the same length
Can I tell matplotlib to use the length of the data-array itself as the xdata and the content as the data? Because it works, if you just put in some numbers in the data variable before the loop.
What about the plt.ion() option?
cheers, Jonas

Comment: @JonasK Ah, just add `l1.set_xdata(np.arange(len(data)))` I think, the plot command assumes that for the xdata...

Comment: Yup, did that. Got rid of error. But plot doesn't show up. I used 'l1.set_xdata(range(len(data)))'. Although nothing happends, I can tell that the loop works. I looks like the plot is not responding or something, but it doesn't block code execution.

Comment: @JonasK, sorry... I didn't really try. I think you may need to either use events with stdin or actually not use pyplot but the object orientated interface with embed matplotlib (its really not hard), to avoid magic done by matplotlib for the interactive session.

Comment: No worries:) I just thought this to be the easiest way. Since I am going to do something with toolkits anyways, I might just try it this way then. Someday I will win this fight against that bugarmy(hopefully)...

BTW, what do you recommend as a toolkit though? Wx, TK, GTK? Wx&TK are shipped with Enthought already I think.

Comment: @JonasK, hah stupid me... what was wrong was autoscaling, updated the answer a bit.

Comment: Awww, it works! :) Thank you very much! Awesome! Now I can try my best in smoothing the line or implementing it in a GUI.
Thanks again, Jonas

Answer (score 2):

Replotting the data seemed to work for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, re
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    if sys.stdin.isatty():
        print "Please use a pipe as stdin\nExample: ping stackoverflow.com | python script.py"
        return 0
    regex = re.compile('time=(\d+.\d+)')

    data = [0]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    #l1, = ax.plot(data)
    fig.show()

    while True:
        #get ping, if no string: stream has ended
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        if line == '':
            break
        #conversion: 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=45 time=100.873 ms --> 100.873
        match = regex.findall(line)
        number = 0.

        if len(match) > 1:
            raise ValueError()
        if len(match) == 1:
            try:
                number = float(match[0])
            except ValueError as e:
                print e
        #add number to array, plot the data
        data.append(number)
        l1, = ax.plot(data, 'r')
        plt.draw()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
        sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Can I ask a question about running this?                   chimpsarehungry$ ping facebook.com | ./ping-matplot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ping-matplot.py", line 5, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: Is this how I would call it from terminal? I get this error above. I do have enthought, but I have to open ipython to get it. Can I run this program from within ipython?

Comment: In your terminal: `ping facebook.com | ./ping-matplot.py`
Make sure the `ping-matplot.py` has execution attributes set, otherwise `python ping-matplot.py`. Nevertheless your problem comes from the absence of matplotlib. Check the [installation](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html).